# Editing favorite URL

Tags: windows-10-mobile, microsoft-edge

1. How can I edit URL in Edge favorites?
2. How can I add link from page directly to favorites?

Comment: Ok, so it seems there is more clutter and less functionality in IE compared to 8.x WP. Is this a good thing nowadays?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean Edge? There is no IE in Windows 10 Mobile.

Comment: @Indrek yes, Edge in WP 10.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it seems that currently the answer to both of your questions is, **you can't**.

1. It's not possible to edit the URL of a favourite. As a workaround, you can open the favourite, change the URL in the address bar, add that back to favourites and then delete the old one.
2. It also doesn't look like you can add the target of a link directly to favourites (though you can add it to reading list). You'll have to open the link, then add the opened page to favourites.

If you need this functionality, you may want to let Microsoft know using the Feedback Hub.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what [@Indrek](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/1401/indrek) said in his [answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/13898/18061), there is an additional workaround.

You can use tools like [Edge Manage](http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/EdgeManage.html) in PC to edit bookmarks, folders, etc... and sync them back to your phone. This may be a bit of work but it provides additional functionalities like local backup of bookmarks. Although it requires the use of a PC it may be highly useful when you require to edit in bulk.

Comment: Tnx, it would be great to have mobile app for that.

Comment: @mpapec I am not sure if it is possible. But anyways, you could ask the developer. You can find his contact info in this webpage. http://www.emmet-gray.com/AboutMe.html.